# Spatie Laravel permissions eager loaded

Tags: laravel-5.8, user-permissions, laravel-permission

First time using this awesome package, and I am trying to eager load permissions for a user.

this returns the roles in a relation:

```
auth()->user()->with('roles')->first();
```

but this returns an empty relation:

```
auth()->user()->with('permissions')->first();
```

How do I eager load permissions? The user I am using as an example is Super Admin, so it should contain an array of all permissions.

What did I miss? Thanks

Comment: Try this to get all auth user roles `User::select('id')->with(['roles'=>function($s){
   return $s->select('roles.name as r_name');
  }])->first();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this piece of code try

**For Roles:-**

```
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;
use HasRoles;


$roles = User::select('id')->with(['roles'=>function($s){
            return $s->select('roles.name as r_name');
        }])->first();
OR

$roles = auth()->user()->with(['roles'=>function($s){
            return $s->select('roles.name as r_name');
        }])->first();
```

**For permissions :-**

```
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission;

$user = Auth()->user();
$permissions = $user->getAllPermissions();

OR

$permissions = auth()->user()->getAllPermissions();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `auth()->user()->with('roles.permissions')->first();`
to eager load both

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).